# Can I open projects built with Xcode 12 in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

So I received this react native project, as a devops I have to get the app out of it and deploy to play store as well as Apple AppStore. I have successfully gotten the android apk but I have been having issues getting the release bundle for iOS. It says the project was built with a higher version of Xcode (probably Xcode 12), but I am using Xcode 11. Please is there anyway around this since I can not install Xcode 12 on my Mac due to it being outdated.